# Mapped array to relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, geocoding

I have the following model associations:

A **concert** has_one **location**. Location is a polymorphic association (concerts are not the only locatables). The location is geocoded through its address attribute by the [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder).

The goal is to find a concert near a certain city that will take place in the future. While the geocoder gem provides the `.near(address_string)` method to find a record by an address, I can only apply that method to the location class, not to the concert class.

I have come up with the following workaround:

```
Location.near("Berlin").where(locatable_type: 'Concert').map(&:locatable)
```

Let me break this down:

```
Location.near("Berlin")
# ==> returns locations of any kind near Berlin

.where(locatable_type: 'Concert')
# ==> returns concert locations near Berlin

.map(&:locatable)
# ==> returns an array of concerts near Berlin
```

The problem is that this returns an *array* of concerts, but I would prefer a relation so that I can use my `upcoming` concert scope to find only concerts that take place in the future.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `ActiveRecord::Relation` doing this:

```
locatable_ids = Location.near('Berlin').where(locatable_type: 'Concert').map(&:locatable_id)
@concerts = Concert.where(id: locatable_ids).upcoming
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev why doesn't it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP wants something different. One query, not two.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm sorry, I can't find this requirement in question. Could you show me appropriate fragment?

Comment: Marek: that's what I inferred. Else why would he want to get a relation?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev "The problem is that this returns an array of concerts, but I would prefer a relation so that I can use my upcoming concert scope to find only concerts that take place in the future."

Comment: Yes, a relation instead of an array. But you still return array from that query.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - yes, from that query. But he has relation of `Concert` objects, on which he can call `upcoming` scope, which, if I understood correctly, solves at least one of his problems.

Comment: Marek: anyway, I don't know how to achieve that in single query, so your answer is the best so far. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think it's impossible (or at least very, veeeeery difficult) to achieve this in single query without changing DB schema.  Even the `includes` scope produces two queries.

Comment: This is elegant enough ;-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I put this in another scope: `scope :near, ->(address, radius = 50) { where(id: Location.near(address, radius).where(locatable_type: 'Concert').map(&:locatable_id)).upcoming }` - so now I can just say `Concert.near("Berlin", 50)` and it works :)